# PyQt5 - Get QGridLayout of QFileDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm trying create my own QFileDialog in PyQt5 to make some slight modifications to its original QGridLayout.

In PyQt4, I simply subclassed QFileDialog and called self.layout() somewhere in the __init__, which returned QFileDialog's QGridLayout and I was then free to do what I needed.

Recently though, I've been forced to switch to PyQt5 in Python3. self.layout(), findChildren(), and the like haven't been returning the same results (sometimes returns None).

So again, I'm trying to get the QGridLayout instance of a QFileDialog in PyQt5. Also, I am using python 3.5, if that changes anything. Anyone know how?

Edit 1 - Added an example:

PyQt4 - Tested on Python 2.7.10

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class MyQFileDialog(QtGui.QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQFileDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        print(self.layout())  # <=--- Returns <PyQt4.QtGui.QGridLayout object>


def window():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = MyQFileDialog()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

PyQt5 - Tested on Python 3.5.2

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyQFileDialog(QtWidgets.QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQFileDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        print(self.layout())  # <=--- Returns None


def window():
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = MyQFileDialog()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain what "haven't worked" means, and provide some example code. The methods you mention all work exactly as expected in PyQt5, and return the same things.

Comment: I added two examples as an edit to the post. They do not return the same things in my experience.

Comment: Qt5 doc on QFileDialog states that `layout()  will return null` as qt tries to use native dialogs. The doc also suggests setting `DontUseNativeDialog` flag. But when I try to set it, `layout()` remains `None` and I get segfault on exit. So I gave up.

Comment: @user3626104. I tested on linux using pyqt-5.3.2, pyqt-5.6 and pyqt-5.7 and they all output a `QGridLayout`. Also `print(self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLabel))` shows the expected list of objects. What are the exact versions of qt and pyqt you are using, and on which platform?

Comment: @user3626104. PS: do you get a native file-dialog dialog when using the `QFileDialog` constructor with PyQt5, or Qt's built-in file-dialog?